# In perforce is the Pending Changelist number and Submitted Chanelist same or different?

Tags: perforce

In perforce is the Pending Changelist number and Submitted Chanelist same or different ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes".  Sometimes a changelist retains its number when submitted, but sometimes it is renumbered.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4guide/Content/P4Guide/create-numbered-changelists.html

The properties of changelist numbers in a nutshell are:

- All changelist numbers (including pending changelists) are unique.
- **All submitted changelist numbers are monotonically increasing with respect to the time of submit.**

Hence, if the latest submitted changelist is 99, and you create a pending changelist 100, and submit it immediately, it will still be changelist 100 after submit.

If changelist 101 is submitted before you submit changelist 100, it is allowed to remain changelist 100 for as long as it's pending (since pending changelists are unordered), but on submit it will be renumbered to the next available number (102) in order to preserve ordering of submitted changelists.